# Datastore Local Unit Testing

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

All, I am new to GCD and want to setup my LocalTestEnvironment. I have successfully installed GCD local environment. I am following this link to do some unit testing https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting

However, I am getting following error while the running simple as below query

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.TestLocalServerEnvironment.enforceApiDeadlines()Z
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxy.java:201)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeAsyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryRunnerV3.runQuery(QueryRunnerV3.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.runQuery(PreparedQueryImpl.java:31)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.asIterator(PreparedQueryImpl.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedMultiQuery$FilteredMultiQueryIterator.makeQueryIterator(PreparedMultiQuery.java:233)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedMultiQuery$FilteredMultiQueryIterator.<init>(PreparedMultiQuery.java:201)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedMultiQuery.newFilteredMultiQueryIterator(PreparedMultiQuery.java:425)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedMultiQuery.asIterator(PreparedMultiQuery.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BasePreparedQuery$1.iterator(BasePreparedQuery.java:25)
    at MultiFilterQuery.main(MultiFilterQuery.java:36)
```

My Testcode

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.Filter;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterPredicate;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilter;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilterOperator;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.*;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.client.Datastore;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreHelper;

import java.util.*;
import static com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreHelper.makeValue;

public class MultiFilterQuery {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Datastore datastore = null;
//  datastore = DatastoreHelper.getDatastoreFromEnv();
    LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
              new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
    helper.setUp();
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    List<String> Dept = Arrays.asList("ECE", "CSE");
    Filter DeptFilter =
              new FilterPredicate("Department",
                                  FilterOperator.IN,
                                  Dept);
    Query q = new Query("StudentMarks").setFilter(DeptFilter);
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
    for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
          String firstName = (String) result.getProperty("StudentName");
          String lastName = (String) result.getProperty("Department");
          Long height = (Long) result.getProperty("Email");

          System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + height + " inches tall");
        }
}
```

}

Comment: This error seems to come when your code changes during execution. To help debug this, can you run the basic example in the docs? working with the basic, looking at it, then expanding it for your needs might work.

Comment: Do you want to test code that will run inside of App Engine or code that will run from some other compute environment and use the Cloud Datastore API? Your sample code is mixing these two scenarios, and they aren't currently compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to run this from external compute engine, but however i got to know from other forums, Cloud Datastore API for external compute engine is still Beta and lot of functions are not supported. Also there seems to high latency between Google Compute Engine and Datastore. We decided to utilize Amazon Dynamodb for application.